# Angularjs display and validate a form filed from a json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'd like to display a form containing validation and a submit button.

I'm new with Angular, and I'm not intireli sure how to get started.
 - I'd like to get a direction of what to do or perhaps some initial
   indication, of what Controller to use.
JS:

```
myApp.controller('jsonCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('form.json').success(function(result) {

});
```

HTML:

```
    <form  ng-controller="jsonCtrl">
        <fieldset>
            <div demo-directive ng-repeat="field in fields">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3AapBB2qUcNN5SCwrZSH?p=preview)

Comment: Here is an example http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI with clear instruction of validating form with submit form using angular. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AshishPanchal thanks, my issue, also is integrating and displaying the json into my html.

Comment: You need to change so many things in plunker. I have corrected some http://plnkr.co/edit/MmMBJqnnRjl1QCIczYzG?p=preview Better you go through the angular docs before you start doing the things

Comment: somehting like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/MmMBJqnnRjl1QCIczYzG?p=preview

Comment: @user3699998 that's your correct working plunker. Now brief your question about what you are trying to populate in HTML and What you are trying to validate?

Comment: @NagaveerGowda, I'm trying to display what is on the json, and make a form field on my html, and display the answers which returns true or
false depending on whether the answer provided was correct. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

*I'd like to display a form containing validation and a submit button.*

You just need to write simple HTML for this

*now, as I'm new with Angular, I apologise about that, I'd like to get a direction of what to do or perhaps some initial indication, of what Controller to use*

Generally people bind a specific section to a specific controller and, obviously that is going to be the case for you.

In the controller you'll have two methods which will address to submit and validate buttons.

```
<my-form>
    <form ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div my-directive ng-repeat="field in fields">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
<button type = "button" ng-click="onValidate(); return false;"> Validate</button>
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</my-form>
```

Now, the main div or body etc. which is parent for the code written above and is linked to a specific controller will have two functions to address to `onValidate()` & `submitForm()`

Comment: Thansk, for this, I've slightly updated my plunker, which is not more clear, could you please check?